# Post back to server when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript

When javascript is disabled in browser then onclick button will post back to server.

Comment: Sorry, but are you telling us, or asking us?

Comment: You need to rephrase this so we can tell what you're asking.

Comment: @Sîme: Tags like guess-the-question are discouraged (similar to "possible-homework"). That's what close votes ("not a real question") are meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal `type="submit"` input or button and `<form>` combination (been around forever), like this:

```
<form action="mypage.htm" method="post">
  //fields..
  <input type="submit" value="Click to submit" />
</form>
```

In JavaScript, handle the `submit` event of the `<form>`...so you capture the submit, do something with JavaScript is enabled (AJAX submission for example), but it's not *not* enabled, it degrades gracefully and will submit to the server/do a full page refresh.

---

If you have the reverse problem that it's already like this and you *don't* want the submit behavior, then don't use a submit button...but I advise against this, since your site *should* degrade gracefully for JavaScript disabled users.

Comment: @Oded - only on Tuesdays, and full moons.

Comment: Looking forward to your act this coming Tuesday, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='return doSomthing();' />
```

and then right a javascript function

```
function doSomething()
{
   return false; // to prevent submit
}
```

Comment: I think you missed both the title *and* the question: "javascript is disabled"

Comment: That won't work when the user has JavaScript disabled, which I understood was the OP's issue.

Comment: Yes, it will (if it is placed inside a form). When javascript is enabled, the doSomething can do the XHR and prevents normal posting of the form. When javascript is disabled, the dosomething is not executed and the form is submitted normally.

Comment: @Jan - A `submit` button isn't the only way to submit a form, and this is a bad approach to attaching it in any case, go the unobtrusive route.

Comment: @Nick: you are correct +1. I just wanted to explain that this example works. I would have done it the other way myself.

Comment: @Jan - I think you're missing a bit of context, when the comments where made the `<input...>` didn't show up in the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4237943/revisions

Answer (score 1):

In case your "button" is part of a `<form>` and that forms action is `post` then yes, your form will gracefully degrade and do a normal post request to the server.

PS: Shouldn't a "Sr. Web Developer" know something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is to make sure that the site works with pure HTML when JavaScript is disabled. Sometimes it means writing separate handlers for HTML form posts and Ajax form posts, sometimes you might be able to modify your code to work with both methods.

If you design the app JavaScript only, you can initially hide the JavaScript form or the button and restore it using JavaScript so that the HTML only user doesn't get to click it. You can use the noscript tag to inform the user to turn JS on, for example:

```
<form style="display:none;" id="ajaxForm">
    (form content)
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#ajaxForm' ).show();  // using jQuery here but can be done with pure JS
</script>

<noscript>
    Sorry, but you need to enable JavaScript.
</noscript>
```